# what is the difference when using var vs typealias

Tags: ios, function, swift2, var, type-alias

I am defining my function as the variable by using `typealias` and `var`( or `let`)

```
typealias IntFuction = (Int) -> Int

var IntFuction = (Int) -> Int
```

If am using `typealias`, there are no error at all. However if I am trying to use either `var` or `let`, I am getting the error like below

```
consecutive statement on a line must be separated by ";"
```

With the [closure](http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com), it should be fine if you can use either `typealias` or `var` to define as a variable

Can anybody explain what is happening when I am using `var` to define the function as the variable

Comment: you are confusing the actual type and its value! Use a `:` instead of the `=` in the second line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typealias IntFuction = (Int) -> Int`. Define a type `IntFuction` same as  `(Int) -> Int`

`var IntFuction = (Int) -> Int` is incorrect

`var IntFuction: (Int) -> Int`
Declare a variable `IntFuction` has type: `(Int) -> Int`

Answer (score 1):

A `typealias` is a synonym for a type or a closure.

An example from the Foundation framework is

```
typealias NSTimeInterval = Double
```

after that declaration `NSTimeInterval` can be used everywhere instead of `Double`.

---

In your case

```
typealias IntFunction = (Int) -> Int
```

you can declare a variable of that type (see the different spelling)

```
var intFunction : IntFunction = { counter in
   return 2 + counter
}
```

which is exactly the same as

```
var intFunction : (Int) -> Int = { counter in
   return 2 + counter
}
```

The error occurs because a type cannot be assigned (`=`) to a variable, the compiler expects an annotation (`:`)